# How to verify a function is $r$-concave in the sense that $ f(x, \, ty) \geq t^{r} f(x, y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

Given a multivariable function $f:   \mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is defined by $$ f( x, y) = ( x^{s} + \beta y^{s})^{1/s} $$ where $s$ is some positive constant and $\beta \in (0,1)$. And it is increasing in both arguments.

I was wondering that for what kind of condition for $s$, the above function $f$ will satisfy the following statement?

There exists $r \in (0,1)$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ , $y \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$  and $t \in (0,1]$, it holds $$ f(x, \, ty) \geq t^{r} f(x, y)$$

I guess the condition that ensures this statement is valid might be $s>1$ (or, maybe $0<s<1$), but I am not sure how to verify it. Could anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: Do you mean $f(\color{red}{t}x,ty)\geq t^r f(x,y)$?

Comment: No, @Mark. It is $f(x, ty) \geq t^{r}f(x,y)$. Thanks ^_^